# Check if a line exists in one file, to all other lines in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have three files, two are being opened for reading and the last I am writing to.  I would like to go through every line in one read file and check if that line exists in the other read file.  Then output to the write file the lines that are the same and blanks if they don't exist.  I cannot figure out how to compare one line, to all lines and do that for each line.

I have tried the following code with the example text files:

```
import os

file_path = os.getcwd()

output_file = os.path.join(file_path, "output_file.txt")
read_file1 = os.path.join(file_path, "read_file1.txt")
read_file2 = os.path.join(file_path, "read_file2.txt")

with open(output_file, 'w+') as write:
    write.write("")

with open(read_file1, 'r') as read1:
    with open(read_file2, 'r') as read2:
        with open(output_file, 'a+') as write1:
            for line in read1:
                if line in read2:
                   write1.write(line)
                else:
                   write1.write("blank\n")
```

Contents of read_file1:

```
test1
test2
test4
test6
test8
test9
test44
test109
```

Contents of read_file2:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test8
test9
test11
test44
test45
test99
test109
test276
```

The expected output in output_file would be:

```
test1    
test2
blank
test4
blank
test6
test8
test9
blank
test44
blank
blank
test109
blank
```

Instead the output I get is:

```
test1
test2
test4
test6
test8
test9
test44
blank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invert `read1` and `read2` in the `for` loop. ([demo](https://repl.it/@riless/57630340))

```
# ...

with open(read_file1, 'r') as read1:
  f1 = read1.read().split()

with open(read_file2, 'r') as read2:
  f2 = read2.read().split()

with open(output_file, 'w+') as write1:
  for line in f2:
    if line in f1:
      write1.write(line + '\n')
    else:
      write1.write('blank\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you

```
import os

file_path = os.getcwd()

output_file = os.path.join(file_path, "output_file.txt")
read_file1 = os.path.join(file_path, "read_file1.txt")
read_file2 = os.path.join(file_path, "read_file2.txt")

read_list = []
with open(read_file1,'r') as read1:
    for i in read1:
        read_list.append(i)
    j = len(read_list)
    read_list[j-1] = read_list[j-1] + "\n"
print(read_list)

write_list = []
with open(read_file2,'r') as read2:
    for line in read2:
        if(line in read_list):
            write_list.append(line)
        else:
            write_list.append("blank\n")
with open(output_file, 'w+') as write1:
    for i in write_list:
        write1.write(i)
```